# How can I get the tooltip text on reddit?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web, web-scraping

I am trying to build some kind selenium **scraper** for reddit. However, I do find myself having some trouble to get the timestamp shown in the pic.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from time import sleep # this should go at the top of the file
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

sleep(5)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/StockMarket/')

title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h3._eYtD2XCVieq6emjKBH3m').text
timestamp = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a._3jOxDPIQ0KaOWpzvSQo-1s').text
print(title)
print(timestamp)

[Output]: We’ve been doing it all wrong
          5 hours ago
```

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ph0d.png)

Answer (score 0):

To get the timestamp (time when content was posted) use css selector:

```
timestamp = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[data-click-id=timestamp]._3jOxDPIQ0KaOWpzvSQo-1s')
```

See here how to work with dataframes. It's a good example [Feed dataframe with webscraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67165356/feed-dataframe-with-webscraping)

The locator posts list would be:

```
post = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('._1poyrkZ7g36PawDueRza-J._11R7M_VOgKO1RJyRSRErT3 ')
```

Getting a tooltip locator is a little tricky. You won't see it unless you hover a mouse on timestamp.
This works just perfectly: `._2J_zB4R1FH2EjGMkQjedwc.u6HtAZu8_LKL721-EnKuR[style]`
[image]

Check this answer on how to inspect elements on hover [Inspect hovered element in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370838/inspect-hovered-element-in-chrome)

Comment: But how can I inspect the element if I need to hover the mouse on it? Can you explain it in detail? Thank you.

Comment: I have tried but this error pops up.                                                                                                                   
date = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2J_zB4R1FH2EjGMkQjedwc u6HtAZu8_LKL721-EnKuR').text                                              
                                                                                                  NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".div._2J_zB4R1FH2EjGMkQjedwc u6HtAZu8_LKL721-EnKuR"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)

Comment: right now I can find the proper class name and xpath of the tooltip text, but I cannot access the text with neither the find_element_by_class_name or find_element_by_xpath method. The following error pops up: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[7]/div/text()"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)

Comment: You won't access it without hovering mouse on it.